# Virtualbox 4.X not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

I upgraded to Ubuntu to 15.10 and suddenly VirtualBox isn't working any more. So I tried to install an older version, but that didn't work. Downgrading also didn't help.

> The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
> 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
> reason is shown below:
>
> Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
> that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions
> listed below to use Vagrant:
>
> 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3

Is there any option to install virtualbox version 4.X (i.e. 4.3, 4.0, 4.1 or 4.2) on Ubuntu 15.10? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Is your version of vagrant up-to date?  Their website indicates that [they support VirtualBox 5](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/index.html)

Comment: ye now it works .... :) buut actually i need vagrant 1.7.2 for my project :-P but im fine!

thnx alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the most recent version of VirtualBox - currently version 5.0.8 - available for Wily as of now.

First you have to remove every VirtualBox related software you already had installed before.

```
sudo apt-get purge  "^virtualbox-.*"  
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then download and register the ORACLE public key:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the VirtualBox repository to software sources :

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Now install VirtualBox :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Download the matching Extension Pack from [VirtualBox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) -  add it manually in Preferences.

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 15.10 :**

You have to replace `wily` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !

Comment: hehe, 4 sure!


so this error appered when i tried to isntall the virtualbox.deb:

Breaks existing package 'virtualbox' that conflict: 'virtualbox'.  But the 'home/USER/Downloads/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.8-103449-Ubuntu-wily_i386.deb' provides it via:'virtualbox'

i dont have a clue what that means

Comment: it works now, i just updated vagrant .... thnx alot anyway! :)

Comment: This might be due to some configuration difference with my system, but I got the error `E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-5` and had to instead use the command `apt-get install virtualbox-5.0` when following these instructions today.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes : Thank you for your hint ... was a little overseen error ...  I updated the answer ! :)

Comment: I didn’t know if it was a typo, or a difference in how my own XUbuntu box got the repo data delivered. Thanks for updating the answer!